# Submitting form without redirects in Django

Tags: django, redirect, django-templates, django-forms

In my main page I have included a template with form for adding emails to newsletter. I'd like this form to add new emails without redirecting anywhere. How I can achieve that ? Here is my code, when I was using separate page for this :

views :

```
def newsletter_add(request):
    if request.POST:
        f = NewsletterForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            try:
                e = NewsletterEmails.objects.get(email = request.POST['email'])
                msg = u'Mail already added'
                return render_to_response('newsletter/add.html',
                    {'form':f,'msg':msg,},RequestContext(request))
            except Address.DoesNotExist:
                e = NewsletterEmails(email = request.POST['email'])
                e.save()
                msg = u'Mail added'
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        f = NewsletterForm()
    return render_to_response('newsletter/add.html',{'form':f,},RequestContext(request))
```

form :

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="center-right">
        <div class="pane profile">
            <div class="div-content">
                {{ msg }}
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{form.as_p}}
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Ok" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms :

```
class NewsletterEmails(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict,maxlength=75)),label=_("email"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

without redirecting anywhere means

1. the form submission should not redirect (or)
2. after submitting the form user should be redirected to the same page with the form.

in case-1 you can do this using [jquery-ajax-forms](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

in case-2 after the post request redirect the user to the same page instead of redirecting to '/'

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('redirect/to/form/page')
```